# How to store the results of a method in a variable that I can then use outside the class in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

The structure in `page-bulletins.php`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => $paged
);

 $query = new WP_Query($args); if( $query->have_posts() ) :
     while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
         <!-- some code -->
     endwhile;
     // call the function 'posts_per_page' in the class 'cn_pages' using the value defined with the 'posts_per_page' key in '$args' above
     cn_pages::posts_per_page($args['posts_per_page']);
     // then call this function
     pass_page_info();
 endif;
```

The code in `functions.php`:

```
class cn_pages {
    function posts_per_page($postsperpage) {
        return $postsperpage;
    }
}
```

I have another function defined outside of the class `cn_pages` that needs the result of the `posts_per_page` method in order to calculate how many total pages there are.

How can I store the result of this method into a variable that I can access outside of the class where the method is defined?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do something like this:

```
class cn_pages {

    public static $postperpage = 0;

    function posts_per_page($postsperpage) {

        self::$postsperpage = $postsperpage;

        return $postsperpage;
    }
}
```

then receiving the result of `cn_pages::posts_per_page()` is:

```
pass_page_info(cn_pages::$postsperpage);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following:

```
$cnpages = new cn_pages();
$cnpages->posts_per_page($args['posts_per_page']);
```

And this should return you the value of the function.

Comment: Thank you for this. It coincides with a lot of what I have read online, although my code was `$cnpages = new cn_pages();`  `$cnpagesout = $cnpages->posts_per_page($args['posts_per_page']);`. Neither one worked for me, though. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
class cn_pages {
    protected $foo;
    function posts_per_page($postsperpage) {
        $this->foo = $postsperpage;
    }

    public function get_foo(){
        return $this->foo;
    }
}


// outside of class create an instance of the class and call the function get_foo()


function outside_of_class(){
    $bar = new cn_pages;
    $foobar = $bar->get_foo(); // here you stored the result of the method in a variable
}
```